# C++ string size_t

Tags: c++, g++, runtime-error, size-t

The following code works as expected i.e., it prints the string in reverse

```
std::string s("abcd");

for (int i=s.length()-1; i>=0; --i) {
    std::cout << s[i];
}
```

However, the following code goes into infinite loop printing junk characters and finally crashes-

```
std::string s("abcd");

for (std::size_t i=s.length()-1; i>=0; --i) {
    std::cout << s[i];
}
```

Why using `size_t` as type of `i` crashes the program?

Am using g++ shipped with MinGW on Windows

```
C:/MinGW/bin/g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 6.1.0
```

Comment: GCC can [warn](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ce861d53b647251b) you about this: *warning: comparison of unsigned expression >= 0 is always true [-Wtype-limits]*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because `std::size_t` cannot store negative numbers and therefore the condition is always true

Answer (score 4):

An unsigned type will never have a negative value. Hence, the conditional
`i>=0` will always evaluate to `true`.

Comment: perhaps you meant unsigned